# insert string at index ignoring html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Is it possible to insert a string, in my case `<br>` at a specific index ignoring HTML tags ?

I have `<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px">Here is my text</span>`

Is it possible to add the 
 after `HER` , or any other solution is welcomed

It should look : `<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px">Her<br>e is my text</span>`

Edit:

I need to call a function like :

```
insertBR(htmlContent,3)
```

Comment: What governs the index at which the `<br />` should be inserted in to the string?

Comment: Grab only the text when manipulating? `innerText`.

Comment: I have a problem with text wrapping and i managed to obtain the index where the text goes on a new line and now i want to insert a <br> where i need in the original text and i can't seem to get it right

Comment: @Teemu obviously when you output you'd use `innerHTML`, I was only suggesting that when he first gets the text for manipulation use `innerText` so he won't get all the extra HTML, then when he puts it back in to the `span` he should use `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something rather simple with some jquery and string replacement.

```js
/*
Gets the text of the element then matches every 3 letters into an array then joins them with <br>
*/
var text = replaceText($('span').text(), 3);
$('span').html(text);

function replaceText(string, index) {

  return string.match(new RegExp(".{1," + index + "}", "g")).join('<br>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Here is my text</span>
```

**EDIT**

Added index

Comment: I think i asked wrong. I have the index : 3 and at index 3 i need to insert a <br>

Comment: Editted to get the index of every three